# Создание объектов, метод forEach для JSON

Tags: javascript, foreach

Что происходит в функции(person), можете написать по порядку?

Как происходит поиск имени? то что forEach проходит по каждому элементу понятно, но непонятно что происходит в этих строчках:

```
byName[person.name] = person;
...
console.log(byName["Philibert Haverbeke"]);
```

```js
var ANCESTRY_FILE = JSON.stringify([
  { "name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "born": 1832 },
  { "name": "Emma de Milliano", "born": 1876 },
  { "name": "Philibert Haverbeke", "born": 1907 },
]);

var ancestry = JSON.parse(ANCESTRY_FILE);

console.log(ancestry.length);

var byName = {};

ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  byName[person.name] = person;
});

console.log(byName["Philibert Haverbeke"]); // → {name: "Philibert Haverbeke", …}
```

Comment: В `byName` записывается имя `person.name` как ключ и вся строка `person` в качестве значения.

Comment: Массив" и "Объект" знакомы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [Скобочная нотация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_Bracket_notation)

Любое значение объекта можно получить через `объект["название_ключа"]`, или присвоить ему `объект["название_ключа"] = "Новое значение";` Вместо строки - внутри квадратных скобок может быть переменная или любое другое выражение.

Но когда ключ - обычная строка без пробелов или специальных символов, используют "точку", просто потому что так короче.

```js
let test = {
  "one_one": "1111",
  "two two": "2222",
  "#@$@#%$": "3333",
};

console.log( test.one_one );    // "1111"
console.log( test["one_one"] ); // "1111"

console.log( test["two two"] ); // "2222"

let key = "#@$@#%$";
console.log( test[key] ); // "3333"

test[key] = "Новое значение";

console.log( test[key] ); // "Новое значение"


document["body"]["style"]["background-color"] = "#922";
// Работает даже так
```

А в вашем примере, во время перебора, на каждой итерации, `person` получает значение очередного объекта вида `{ "name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "born": 1832 }`

`byName[person.name] = person;` — в заранее созданный пустой объект `byName = {}` добавляются все объекты person, а ключами служат их значения `person.name`

Answer (score 0):

Простыми словами, создаётся map коллекция с ключом и значением, где в качестве ключа выступает *.name и дальше мы можем просто получить значение из коллекции, обратившись к ней по ключу.

Советую прочесть - [MDN Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)